# how to implement a randlong in numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy

For the following code, I want to generate random value but the value in `dfCombined["TotalFreeSize"]` can be up to  `9.941458e+11`, and it throws error for `randint`, what should I do?

And I can't find a `randlong` function..

```
# get average, std, and number of NaN values in col
average_age_test   = dfCombined["TotalFreeSize"].mean()
std_age_test       = dfCombined["TotalFreeSize"].std()
count_nan_age_test = dfCombined["TotalFreeSize"].isnull().sum()

rand_1 = np.random.randint(average_age_test - std_age_test, average_age_test + std_age_test, size = count_nan_age_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

randint takes two values as parameters, both ints. a lower bound value and a higher bound value. it will than return an int between those values.

mean(), std() in the other hand return float values, as the mean and std of a set of values.

what you should do is give parameters that are int into the randint function.

you can:

```
 average_age_test   = int ( dfCombined["TotalFreeSize"].mean() )
 std_age_test       = int ( dfCombined["TotalFreeSize"].std() )
```

hope that helps! if it does please upvote :)

---

sample:

input:

```
A = int (9.941458e+11)
random.randint(0, A)
```

output:

```
153271550649L    (type: long)
```

Comment: but that will limit the long value to int value?

Comment: i tried it out. generates a random int of long type just fine.

Comment: if you want a random float up to that number you can: random.random()*9.941458e+11

Comment: this is the real value `np.random.randint(1712075075219 - 2859660733559, 1712075075219 + 2859660733559, size = 148)`

Comment: k you using np random function. thats a different library. try: import random, random.randint(...) should work. the only detail is that it doesnt have the size term, but you can put it inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map random values from 0 to 1 (generated with `random`) to your max desired value, and python will cast it appropriately. This seems to work even for very large `max` values:

```
import random

max = 9.941458e91 # notice the '91' exponent here!

for i in xrange(10):
    val = long(random.random() * max)
    print val
    print type(val)
    print
```

Sample output (single value):

```
    45525909158271540655933151699075210889481964268830820171688052775301692920778132706971090944
<type 'long'>
```

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure that's not correct, unless you have one of those top secret 256bit machines. Because with 64 and even 128bit floats your resolution at that magnification is larger than 1, so you won't get every possible int, let alone uniform distribution.

Comment: I suppose that. Anyway, _depending on the requirements_, this could be a viable workaround (although not formally quite what the OP asked for explicitly).